# How do i use a Regex separator that looks like a named group?

Tags: javascript, regex-group

I am splitting a string that contains substrings of this form:

```
 "<at>foo bar</at>"
```

using this construct:

```
tokens = command.trim().split( /,\s+|,|\s+|(?=<at>)|(?=<\/at>)/ )
```

However, the result is an array:

```
["<at>foo", "bar", "</at>"]
```

How do I modify the regex to produce?:

```
["<at>", "foo", "bar", "</at>"]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using split, you might match the parts

```
<\/?at>|[^<>\s]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fHGtfx/1)

```js
const regex = /<\/?at>|[^<>\s]+/g;
console.log(`<at>foo bar</at>`.match(regex));
```

Using split, the pattern could be

```
,\s*|\s+|(?<=<at>)|(?=<\/at>)
```

```js
const regex = /,\s*|\s+|(?<=<at>)|(?=<\/at>)/g;
console.log(`<at>foo bar</at>`.split(regex))
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice answer by @The fourth bird

Another way could be splitting only the string between the tags:

```js
const chars = "<at>foo bar</at>";

const tags = /<\/?at>/g;
const tokens = chars.replace(tags, "").split(/\s/);

const result = ["<at>", ...tokens, "</at>"]

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks @The fourth bird and @Astor - much appreciated. I realize that I also need a variation: split/match parts this way for the first use case and in the second case split/match to end with with  `<at>foo bar</at>`.